# Какой режим работы с файлом использовать, чтобы считать и перезаписать Json Python

Tags: python, json, файлы

В начале работы программы есть маленький `json`, содержащий `false`.

Программа должна вывести изначальное содержимое `json`, **перезаписать** (а не просто добавить в конец) новое значение и вывести уже его.

```py
from json import dump, load

with open('temp.json', '???') as f:
    print(load(f)) # False
    dump(True, f)
    print(load(f)) # True
```

Как я могу это сделать? Какой режим работы с файлом должен использовать?

Comment: `r+` и не забудьте про `seek` и `truncate`

Comment: Поставил `r+`, вызываю `f.seek(0)` и `f.truncate(0)` перед вызовом `dump`. Выпадает исключение `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. Но в сам `json` успешно **перезаписывается** `true`. Если убрать последнюю строчку, то все работает хорошо. Что делать с исключением?

Comment: А вы не забыли сделать seek после dump?

Comment: а что помешало открыть справку по open() и посмотреть, какие там режимы вообще есть, и выбрать из них подходящий? Там не так много вариантов.

Comment: @andreymal поставил `f.seek(0)` после `dump`, работает. Спасибо за помощь, хотя этот способ выглядит как хак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Откройте файл в режиме чтения ('r')
2. Прочитайте
3. Закройте
4. Откройте в режиме записи ('w')
5. Запишите
6. Закройте

Не мудрствуйте лукаво! :-) Самый простой путь - самый надёжный.

Comment: Ага, но формально не является ответом на вопрос